# List of nearby wifi hotspots-objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, wifi

I am a new Objective C programmer. I need some help. I am developing an app in which if the internet connection is not google reachable, it should open up the browser and should check for Wifi Hotspot process. I googled for this but couldnot find any information regarding this. Please help me.

Comment: I don't think Apple allows you to mess with the network settings on their devices.

Comment: But we already have many iPhone apps that list the nearby wifi hotspots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually not code, this is something you have to put on your Info.plist file.

What you are looking for is:

`UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` or `Application uses Wifi`

Here is what Apple has to say about it:

> If your application accesses the network using the Wi-Fi radios, you must notify the system of that fact by including the `UIRequiresPersistentWiFi` key in the application’s Info.plist file. The inclusion of this key lets the system know that it should display the network selection panel if it detects any active Wi-Fi hot spots. It also lets the system know that it should not attempt to shut down the Wi-Fi hardware while your application is running.

Comment: if you found this to be your answer, would you mind setting it as the correct answer? Glad this helped you.